# Pentaho Kettle weird Left Join results

Tags: left-join, pentaho, kettle

I am using kettle too make a left join between two tables who share common keys, however despite in some rare cases the join works as I intended, in most of them it returns NULL despite sharing the same key as in the cases where it works. Like in the example bellow.

EDIT: In one table I have ID_DOENTE and ID_TIPO_CONSULTA, while in other I have TIPO_CONSULTA and ID_TIPO_CONSULTA. I am merging the first table using left join with the 2nd using ID_TIPO_CONSULTA as the key. The result is the following

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the in the rows with ID_DOENTE 40, the join works in a single case, but for all the other rows despite the situation being identical it leaves the values coming from the 2nd table as NULL.

---

[image]

Comment: I would love to help you - but how do you expect somebody to understand what you are doing?

Comment: Ok, I elaborated more. But it's really simple what I am doing. I have two tables, they share one key, and I want to join them according to that key, yet in some situations it joins properly and in others which should be identical it leaves those columns as null.

Comment: well, I used this feature - thousands of other people do and did so as well - so if something is not working in your case, then you have to be specific about what exactly you are doing. does that make sense?

Comment: Well yes, but I really don't know what I should elaborate more, since it's quite a simple situation. I have two tables with two columns (after removing the columns I didn't want that I got from the DB), one of the columns is common between them so I want to join them in a single table, but yet the join is giving me those weird results.

Comment: just a wild guess - did you sort the tables before merging?

Comment: No, what I have is this http://imgur.com/WpP2AJM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding "merge join" step:

> Note: In this step rows are expected to be [sorted](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Sort+rows) on the
>   specified key fields.

[(source)](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Merge+Join)

Comment: Yeah, it was that. I feel dumb, I completely forgot about that.

Comment: don't worry - it's alright, just upvote my answer and I won't tell anybody ;)

Comment: Can't since I made this account recently so I don't have permission for that, really sorry.

Comment: Actually I just got right now the necessary reputation, here you go.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can be using a join without adding the **Sort step**, otherwise unexpected results might come out.

**See what the kettle documentation**.

**Pentaho Documentation**
[** PRINT show: Docs Pentaho about JOINs**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhuf7.png)

Whenever you use a **JOIN** in Pentaho add a **Step Sort** with the join IDs so that the pentaho can sort the results before joining, so you'll be able to sort without any problems.

[**Print - Example JOIN with SORT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSgYD.png)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to external ressources